# How to Restore Wordpress Site Backup in Subdomain?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have backup of my old blog in zip format. Now I have another domain and I created it's subdomain. I want to restore that backup in that subdomain (another domain). I installed the WordPress through cPanel and uploaded the whole backup. Only the plugins get restored but not able to restore my post and pages.

Please help me out if anyone know the solution

Comment: Did you also remember to backup your database? If so, import it via phpmyadmin and update the URLs so they point to the new domain.

Comment: I am not a developer so not very familiar with backup types. My backup is in .tar format. I also have sql backup, if it is the same. can you tell the process after importing it to phpmyadmin. It will be helpful for me.

Comment: No problem. Have a look: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=how+to+restore+a+database+backup+wordpress

Comment: Thanks. Imported the database but steps after this are not mentioned

Comment: You need to set up a new user for the database you created and grant all privileges, then insert the relevant info in wp-config.php. You will also have to go into the options table in your new  wp db and change the website you are pointing to to the new website with subdomain.  there are two or three entries to change if I remember correctly.

Comment: Database and wp-config thing i have already done. I can see two "options" table there wp_options and wpwk_options. Can you please tell the places where i need to edit

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create another database for the backup site. add users to that database so you can use it then check your wp-config.php for the right credentials.

Comment: Yes i have already done it. Created new database and user then added both. Also updated wp-config. Then uploaded backup and unzipped those files. What else do i have to do next

Comment: you should check the site for remaining bugs. check also the wp-options on the database. the home and site url.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the "All-in-One WP Migration" plugin for backup and restore this is the best plugin for migration also for creating the backup, once migration will be done you just need to save once the permalink.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/

Comment: I already tried that. Not able to restore from this plugin. I took the backup manually it is in .tar.gz format but this plugin requires backup file in .wpress format. So it is also not working out for me

Comment: Okay, first go to your live site wp dashboard and then go to All-in-One WP Migration > Export, and when on the export page you will see the "Export To" button will appearing and when you click on it the export button will open the dropdown option, click the file option and the All in one migration will create website backup in wpress file format.

Comment: Actually, it was an old backup. the site is not live now.